# Pandas rolling and ignore rows that have NaN in the count

Tags: python, pandas

### Sample data

```
                                   id  val       date
id           date                                    
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19
             2018-11-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-12-31  SE0000191827    9 2018-12-29
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23
```

(for convenience, create this data using this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/wMU3esEh)

I would like to apply a `rolling` function over the `val` column with a period of 4 but only count the rows in which `val` is not `NaN`. I cannot use `dropna` since I need the rows which have `NaN` to also receive values in a new column. The data I expect is below.

### Expected output

```
                                   id  val       date  calc
id           date                                          
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16  26.0
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT  27.0
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20  27.0
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11   NaN
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19   NaN
             2018-11-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-12-31  SE0000191827    9 2018-12-29   NaN
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31  10.0
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29   NaN
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16   NaN
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23   NaN
```

Notice that the row `(SE0000191827, 2018-03-31)` also should get the value 27.0. The reasoning is that that row has four `val` values below it, so I want to count it.

---

One attempt is the following:

```
(Pdb) df2.assign(calc=(df2.dropna()['val'].groupby(level=0).rolling(4).sum().shift(-3).reset_index(0, drop=True)))
                                   id  val       date  calc
id           date                                          
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16  26.0
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20  27.0
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11   NaN
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19   NaN
             2018-11-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-12-31  SE0000191827    9 2018-12-29   NaN
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31  10.0
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29   NaN
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16   NaN
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23   NaN
```

However, this doesn't get any value for the `(SE0000191827, 2018-03-31)` row since it gets dropped in `dropna`.

---

As far as I can find there is no way of getting `rolling` to skip rows that have `NaN` in them. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using your groupby (removing the nulls first), then `df.reindex(index= <#put original index here>)` to push the original timesteps back into the index, and `df.fillna` over what's been calculated.. those values can be imputed over the dates without a value in `calc` with focb (first observation carried backward).  This is denoted as `ffill` and `bfill` in pandas lingo.

(Basically, add `.reindex(df2.index).groupby(level=0).bfill()` to the end inside your assign function)

Comment: That's a very clever way of solving it that I hadn't thought of. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variant of your attempt to build a Series per group (using apply) and just use `bfill` on that Series to fill the relevant NaN values:

```
def process(sub):
    calc = pd.Series(index=sub.index)
    calc.loc[~sub.val.isna()] = sub['val'].dropna().rolling(4).sum().shift(-3)
    return calc.bfill()

df2['calc'] = df2.groupby(level=0).apply(process).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

It gives as expected:

```
                                   id  val       date  calc
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16  26.0
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT  27.0
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20  27.0
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11   NaN
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19   NaN
             2018-11-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-12-31  SE0000191827    9 2018-12-29   NaN
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31  10.0
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29   NaN
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16   NaN
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23   NaN
```